# Check to see if two nodes are translations of each other

Tags: i18n-l10n

What is the *easiest* way to check to see if two nodes are indeed part of the same translation set? Is there a function or some property that can be used? I am using the i18n suite of modules to perform node translation.

Comment: I don't know this for sure so I won't put it as answer, but checking the `$node->tnid` property of each might work. According to the schema docs for that column: _"The translation set id for this node, which equals the node id of the source post in each set."_

Comment: Where that fails is if they both are 0, then it means none are translated. I was wondering what other people do that maybe cleaner than this.

Comment: Are you using the i18n module, or are you using just the modules that come with Drupal?

Comment: Adjusted my question @kiamlaluno

Comment: try internationalization module

Comment: @monymirza As mentioned in the question, I am using the i18n suite of modules already. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [translation_node_get_translations($tnid)](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!translation!translation.module/function/translation_node_get_translations/7) function :

```
// $node is the node which translation set is needed
// this function returns an array of two node objects
translation_node_get_translations($node->tnid);
```

If you want to test it you need to put it somewhere (a wise place) in the code, clear your cache, and then show it with [devel](http://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module.

Wish helps,

cheers,

jramby.